# Transferring local site to shared hosting

Tags: apache, shared-hosting

I'm looking to setup a simple online text processing tool similar to the [Clang demo](http://llvm.org/demo/). The processing program itself is a C++ program which I can modify to provide the desired output I need. Since I use Linux+Perl daily and have used Apache in the past, I'd like to get this working locally first.

My two questions are:

Is it possible to do this with only Apache and Perl? I've looked into frameworks for doing this and quickly ran into [The Paradox Of Choice](http://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice.html).

Will I be able to easily transfer a working local site to a shared hosting service? I want to administer as little as possible. My understanding is since this needs to run a C++ program that CGI is a requirement and thus I need to administer the httpd server. Hopefully this doesn't mean a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Transferring the site is easy, just FTP it over is the simplist approach. Although you may have to map the folder structure of the hosting company if they want the exe to 'live' in a certain CGI folder (or similar).

I would assume you will need VPS due to installing the C++ exe; you could ask the hosting company about it though and please post the findings.

Comment: Some shared hosting companies allow C++.exe to be used. But you would need to check with them first.